# HTTP Post Web API Only Posting First Element Of Array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I am learning WebAPI and trying to do an HTTP Post and I almost have it working I just cannot figure out how to get it to post the entire array of data.  The count of the array is correct and I am getting no errors it just only posts the first element of the array to my table.

My code is as follows. There is probably an easier way to do this and I am open to any advice or best practices as I am just learning how this all works. Thanks for any tips/ideas on what I am doing wrong.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]List<cert_unit_Angular> unitsPassed)
    {

        cert_unit_Angular CertUnit = new cert_unit_Angular();
        foreach (var element in unitsPassed)
        {
            CertUnit.cc_id = element.cc_id;
            CertUnit.unit_id = element.unit_id;
        }
        db.cert_unit_Angular.Add(CertUnit);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
```

EDIT 1: Client Side That Sends Values (Seems to be working as I am getting the correct count of elements I am sending).

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        url: '/api/PostToTable/Post/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: objdata,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            Console.Log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

EDIT 2: Client Side Code that Gets my values of the array. I am just using a GET to get the data.  This is working for me as I am getting the correct amount of data. I am just struggling with posting more than one row from it.

```
  function getCert(cc_id) {

    $http.get('api/Cert/Get/', { params: { id: cc_id } })
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.selectedclients = data;

        })
}

var objdata = JSON.stringify($scope.selectedclients);
```

EDIT 3. XHR Data Requested.

> Request Payload:
>
> [{"cc_id":7778,"unit_id":"TEST10","$$hashKey":"object:5"},{"cc_id":7778,"unit_id":"TEST11","$$hashKey":"object:6"},{"cc_id":7778,"unit_id":"TEST13","$$hashKey":"object:8"}]
>
> Request URL:http://localhost:28276/api/PostToTable/Post/
>
> Header: 
>   Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Content-Type:application/json
>   Origin:http://localhost:28276
>   Referer:http://localhost:28276/
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
>   X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

(Sorry that formatting is terrible on the header)

The EF Model looks like...

```
public partial class cert_unit_Angular
{
    public string unit_id { get; set; }
    public int cc_id { get; set; }
}
```

unit_id is my primary/entity key.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your client side code that sends the values?

Comment: Added! @behroozdalvandi

Comment: Based on your exchange from Thorarins' answer below, is this an `Angular`/`jQuery` question then? Above you are saying you're getting the "right number", but in your comments below, you are saying _"posting only one"_ (meaning you're actually sending just 1 item from the _client side_ to API)? What does the `XHR` data look like?

Comment: When I say I am getting the "right number" or correct data I am able to set a break and step through my loop and it looks through each row of data I am trying to post but only posts one even though it steps through each one. I will add the XHR data to my original post. Thank you for taking a look @EdSF

Comment: Okay the XHR data is added.  For example it will only post one of my rows of data instead of all three.  Like I said before when I add a break I can inspect my variables and it knows there are three elements in my array and it loops through in my foreach but it only is adding one.  That's why I was thinking it was a syntax error in my WebAPI but now I am not sure after trying just about everything I can think of.

Comment: "Adding one" - where? the database/data store? Assuming I understood, the WebAPI is in fact getting _all_ the data (multiple), and the issue _seems_ to be in  the data side- `db.cert_unit_Angular`(?) - what does your EF(?) model look like?

Comment: Yeah adding one to the database. Sorry I did not explain that better.  But yes the WebAPI is getting all the data but only the one record is going into the actual database.  I added the EF model above.  Thank you so much. @EdSF

Comment: No problem at all - we're *all* learning :) Assuming you want to actually add all 3 "items" (based on that model), _try_ moving the `db.SaveChanges()` in the loop (in Thorarins' code below) - so it saves to db on each iteration. You might hit an exception on the db side (`id`) but that would be a good thing for you move forward - work on the ef/db side. Hth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is dealing with a similar issue I solved my problem by changing my code to this...

```
foreach (var element in unitsPassed)
    {
        cert_unit_Angular CertUnit = new cert_unit_Angular();
        CertUnit.cc_id = element.cc_id;
        CertUnit.unit_id = element.unit_id;

        db.cert_unit_Angular.Add(CertUnit);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

After I did that this it was still throwing an error I believe it was because unit_id was my primary key.  I had to add an identity column to the Entity framework and DB side and then it posted all my rows correctly.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are saving the last item in the list, your problem is that you only have one instance of CertUnit, the new and add need to be inside of the loop

```
 foreach (var element in unitsPassed)
        {
            cert_unit_Angular CertUnit = new cert_unit_Angular();
            CertUnit.cc_id = element.cc_id;
            CertUnit.unit_id = element.unit_id;
            db.cert_unit_Angular.Add(CertUnit);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Still only posting the first one.  Thanks though!

Comment: add the code that generates objdata in the javascript then